# Prevent devxpress parse <b> tag in ASPxPopupControl

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, wcag2.0

First of all sorry about my English I hope not injury your eyes with my awful grammar and I'll appreciate if You tell me some mistake I make.

I've got a devexpress ASPxPopupControl control inside a UserControl that works fine. However i want my control to pass the WCAG validation and i realize the control
renders a line extra in his header ( i don't know this line is for):  `<b class="dx-clear"></b>`.

The validation tool i use says the b tag needs be replaced
with strong tag instead, so: does anybody know how to prevent the control to render `<b class="dx-clear"></b>` ?

This is my devexpress control code:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl
ID="puMessBox"
runat="server"
AccessibilityCompliant="true"
EnableViewState="False"
ClientInstanceName="messageBoxCustom"
Modal="True"
CloseAction="CloseButton"
AllowDragging="True"
ModalBackgroundStyle-BackColor="White"
ShowFooter="true"    
MinWidth="482px"
 ShowHeader="true"     
MinHeight="200px"
FooterStyle-Paddings-Padding="1em"
PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter"
PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter">
<ContentCollection>
    [...]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devexpress add this line in order to prevent further padding to the popup control header. In other words. The following image shows you how the popup header looks like when this line is added `<b class="dx-clear"></b>`

[image]

After removing or changing this line `<b class="dx-clear"></b>` The popupControl header will look like this:
[image]

Unfortunately, I don't think that you can remove devexpress generated html code. One solution could be not to show the whole header if this is a possible in your scenario.